# TestFlight redeem code expiration period

Tags: ios, testflight

i have developed an app and it is going through BETA testing on test flight. I have invited user to external testing and they received an email with redeem code but when they enter the redeem code, error message pop out stated redeem code is expired. I have no idea why, it is just a few hours after the user is notified. So how long it takes for the redeem code on test flight expired?

Comment: If anybody have any idea, I also would like to know... My guess is less than an hour. even if 9 alpha characters give you huge set of possibility....

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a colleague who thinks it should last about a week, but he isn't sure either.

Comment: @Niels Hi, yes it should last about a week provided you didn't click open the URL attached in the email.